# Need a sidebar with columns in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

This is my page where I want changes.

[Please click here](http://designiyer.com/coolfuzz/mayweather-held-all-the-aces/)

In this page, in the side bar, instead of one column, I need two columns. I have tried everything as per my knowledge but they are coming in a vertical fashion, one below the other.

Where do I need to change, so that it will come as columns and not rows.

Can anyone help me here?  Even if there is no perfect answers for this, can someone give me an hint where to apply these changes so that I can think on those lines?

Thanks a lot in advance itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you just need to have another sidebar and then adjust the CSS so the width for the two of them are splitting the width.

Example (modify as needed):

```
<aside class="cb-sidebar clearfix" role="complementary">
Contents Here
</aside>
<aside class="cb-sidebar clearfix" role="complementary">
Contents Here
</aside>


.cb-sidebar {
  width: 150px;
}
.cb-sidebar-widget img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}
```